# Highest Binding Energy per Nucleon

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy, isotopes

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel-62)

Isotope of nickel has the highest binding energy per nucleon. But according to a statement in the standard textbook of our country it is said that Fe has the highest binding energy per nucleon.

[image]

Now I'm confused if I should believe at what is written on the internet or at the textbook that is being used by all high schools in our country. I hope this is not out of topic. Please let me know which element actually has more binding energy per nucleon with a reliable source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in CBSE class $12$, Me too. Preparing for boards? Me too. Hope your revision's going on good!

Okay, coming to the question, then when I was reading this chapter(one of my fav after optics), I also happened to notice this mistake given in NCERT. Actually, wiki is right!

The binding energy per nucleon for $\rm 28\text-Nickel\text-62$ is $8.7944965967742$, but for $\rm 26\text-Iron\text-56$, it is $8.7902483214286$. Clearly, for nickel it is higher.

Evidence? Yeah, I have.

Nickel : [Click here](http://barwinski.net/isotopes/all_isotopes_query_results.php?element=28-Nickel&order_isotopes_by_field=total_binding_energy%2Fmass_number%20DESC&all_radioactive_stable=ALL)

Iron: [Click here](http://barwinski.net/isotopes/all_isotopes_query_results.php?element=26-Iron&order_isotopes_by_field=total_binding_energy%2Fmass_number%20DESC&all_radioactive_stable=ALL)

Note : *The records given in the given links are very helpful for solving various numerical problems on binding energy. So bookmark this page.*